# How to get real size of a CCLabelTTF in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCLabelTTF with a dynamic text. Let's say it has a maxsize of 200,200. I create it:

```
CCLabelTTF * label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello!" dimensions:CGSizeMake(200,200) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:15];
```

This works nicely.

But I have to put something right under, therefore I need to know the height of the text. I've tried label.texture.contentSize, label.contentSize. They both is 200,200.

What can I do here?
I'm using cocos2d 1.x

Comment: as long ad you defined demensions, it's hard. why don't try to remove the dimensions and use the simplest labelWithString ?

Comment: @m.ding Because then I can't have linebreak and alignment

Comment: or just add a \n in your string?

Comment: @m.ding Are you sure that works? Still, I wont be able to choose alignment.

Comment: not quite sure, but worth to try. although you cannot choose the alignment, you can make new lines and get the size. `labelWithString:@"Hello \n World!"`

Comment: @m.ding Yes sure It's a way, but as the text is dynamic It's not a good way. If I want user's to be able to enter this text for instance, I need wordwrap.

Comment: :true. I was thought all the text are under your control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use NSString's sizeWithFont methods.

```
NSString *hello = @"Hello!"
UIFont *font = ...
CGSize *textSize = [hello sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

This should tell you the exact size of the text.

Comment: That's definately a way. Hoped there was a way in just cocos2d though. I guess alignment is contained in the UIFont object (left, right, center)? Thanks, Ill mark as correct if no other answer comes in.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIFont * font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15];
CGSize realSize = [message sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(210, 200) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];    
label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:message dimensions:realSize alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap fontName:@"HelveticaNeue" fontSize:15];
```

This is what I ended up doing based on @Ben answer. It works perfectly!